# How to reuse my configurations and exclude another one in SpringBoot Test?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-test

How can I reuse my main configurations but exclude some..?

Like:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SpringApplicationBuilder(Application.class, 
                ConfigOne.class,
                ConfigTwo.class,
                ConfigThree.class //I want to exclude the ConfigThree in my tests and use my own ConfigThreeTest.class
                ).run(args);
    }
}
```

---

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class MyTests {

    //test...
}
```

---

```
@Configuration
public class ConfigThreeTest {

    //config...

}
```

In the sample above I want to exclude `ConfigThree.class` and use `ConfigThreeTest.class`

Comment: You can't easily do that. Consider using `@Profile` on your configuration class instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `MyTests` class, you can specify which class(es) to be used for the configuration.

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = {ConfigOne.class, ConfigTwo.class},webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using this

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {demo.class})
```

Comment: According this [link](https://spring.io/blog/2016/04/15/testing-improvements-in-spring-boot-1-4), the @SpringBootTest is the "most correct" way... Is necessary the SpringBootApplication?

Comment: `exclude` is used to exclude auto-configuration, not classpath scanning candidates.